# Overwrite Major Version Using Object Model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, versioning, object-model

I have versioning and checkin/checkout enabled in a SharePoint 2010 list, and for business-related reasons, would like to update information in a field: overwriting the field data for all versions in a similar manner and in place so that the version numbers do not change.

If I call SPListItemVersion.ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion(), it fails stating that I need to check out the item before making changes to it. Makes sense. So I precede the update statement with SPListItemVersion.ListItem.CheckOut() statement, attempt the update, and receive an error that I cannot overwrite a published version. I've also attempted to precede the check out with SPSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true, setting it back to false after the update call, but the latter error still occurs. Any ideas?

Stripped code below:

```
foreach (SPListItemVersion itemVersion in item.Versions){
  itemVersion.ListItem.File.CheckOut(SPFile.SPCheckOutType.Online, itemVersion.ListItem.File.TimeLastModified.ToString());
  site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
  itemVersion.ListItem["FieldName"] = "changed value here";
  itemVersion.ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
  site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
  itemVersion.ListItem.File.CheckIn("Updated list item version", SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that may find themselves facing this issue, you do not need to toggle the AllowUnsafeUpdates field. What worked for me is replacing the `itemVersion.ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()` statement with `itemVersion.ListItem.SystemUpdate(false)`. The parameter passed in tells SharePoint to not create a new version when updating.

**Edit:** This answer only updates the current item again. SPListItemVersion field references are available via a `get` only; it appears this is not possible in the object model.